# Is there a Python function that can filter and assign binary value to a column in the dataset based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

Having issue filtering my result dataframe. I have a column in my dataset called `PaymentAmount` which has numerical data and want to perform an operation to assign a value of

- 1 if `data['PaymentAmount'] > 25000` and
- 0 if `data['PaymentAmount'] <= 25000`

I tried using the below

```
1 if data['PaymentAmount'] >= 25000 else 0
```

but getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-176-e368653724d0> in <module>
----> 1 1 if data['PaymentAmount'] >= 25000 else 0

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1574         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1575                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
-> 1576                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1577 
   1578     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is better use vectorized solutions - convert boolean mask to integer for `True/False` to `1/0` mapping:

```
data['new'] = (data['PaymentAmount'] > 25000).astype(int)
```

Or use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
data['new'] = np.where(data['PaymentAmount'] > 25000, 1, 0)
```

---

Your solution should working with lambda function and `apply`, but it is slow, because loops under the hood:

```
data['new'] = data['PaymentAmount'].apply(lambda x: 1 if  x >= 25000 else 0)
```